# Giving a presenation about WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms

As the only developer in our organization who has used WPF for the last couple of years, I've been asked to give a talk about it to other developers.  I was hoping people could suggest how much and what I should cover without making the other developers feel overloaded.

*- The presentation is only for around 30 minutes

 - The rest of the group are all Win Forms developers and some have experience working in Silverlight*

Comment: Sorry, but your question is off-topic.

Comment: 30 minutes is not going to be enough time to provide enough information.  While the underline code is exactly the same, stuff does behave different, which means a solution that works for a windows form application will not work for a WPF application.

Comment: The presentation will only be an introduction to WPF probably writing XAML code, grid, stackpanel etc... I'm just not sure how far deep I can go without making the developers feel overloaded.

Comment: For inspiration, I suggest you have a look at this series by Josh Smith: [A Guided Tour of WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_1.aspx). This is a good starting point for beginners.

Comment: This does not belong here.  Maybe programmers.stackexchange.com.  30 minutes is just and intro.

Answer (score 3):

Show them data binding. It is the one of the most important things to wrap your head around in WPF, and it's also one of the great advantages it has over WinForms.

Comment: I totally agree on this. Additionally its imho the most important point to convince traditional WinForms developers to use WPF when they see the power of databinding.

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by showing some visual examples of what can be achieved through WPF and then describe, using diagrams, how that was achieved.

One great example is the fact you can bind the UI directly to a model - whether this is simply a runtime data type, or something hooked into a back-end database. Just the fact that you don't have to write custom UI update code to re-populate UI elements (like in WinForms) every time the backing data has been updated; is something that sells it for me!

On top of that, you have the whole styling system. It is much easier to mould the appearance of the application to something that your company wants. And it looks much nicer. For example, with the composition rendering system, layers of controls can be transparent - allowing you to create circular buttons where the click area isn't actually a rectangle. Similarly, though perhaps not applicable to you, is the fact you can overlay WPF controls onto a `D3DImage`, which can be used to render 3D content to. So you can have an application built over the top of some 3D imagery.

I would suggest reading through some topics about [WPF on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx). Refreshing yourself over some articles on there may help you identify some really cool aspects of it.